How are $q$-ary linear codes over $\mathbb{F}_{2^s}$ mapped to $\mathbb{F}_2$?
I am currently looking into Algebraic Geometry codes and I noticed they are very good over finite fields of large alphabet sizes. Suppose I have an $[n,k,d]$ code over $\mathbb{F}_{2^s}$. How do I implement such a code in a binary system? My guess is that we use the identity $\mathbb{F}_{2^s}\cong\mathbb{F}_2^s$, so that we obtain an $[sn,sk,d']$ code over $\mathbb{F}_2$, where $d\leq d'$. Is this correct? If so, is it common practice or do more advanced methods exist? How would this affect the decoding algorithms? What is the relevant state-of-the-art literature of implementations of non-binary codes?

I don't know any coding theory, but it is not true that $\mathbb{F}_{2^s} \cong \mathbb{F}_2^s$ (as rings).

Yes, typically the codewords of an $[n,k,d]$ code over $\mathbb F_{2^m}$ (as well as the corresponding "received words") are stored as $mn$-bit vectors in digital electronic systems, but they are not operated on or treated or decoded as codewords of an $[mn,mk, d]$ binary code, or as $m$ interleaved codewords of an $[n,k,d]$ binary code, Instead, the calculations operate on disjoint $m$-bit "chunks" (or bytes) of the $mn$-bit vector to mimic the operations of the encoder or decoder of the code over $\mathbb F_{2^m}$. Search math.SE for "Reed-Solomon codes" to get several discussions of implementation of codes over nonbinary alphabets.

I'm not sure if it applies to the OP's question, but a BCH code encodes using polynomials with single bit coefficients, but decodes by treating those single bits as 0 or 1 in $GF(2^m)$ .
